# improve clarity of my picture

Tags: canon, canon-700d

I use Manual Focus to take pictures. I find picture to be of high quality(clarity) when i see the picture in the camera screen. But if i import the picture to my PC it becomes blurry and not that great in details.
I have tried with L, RAW+L, L (Day and Night). Still the image when viewed in bigger screen looks blurry.
I use Canon 700D (18-55 IS II and 55-250 IS II, AP:3.5 - 5.8) to take pictures. I am new to photography. Seeking some inputs from peers over here with regard to take better quality pictures.

Sample Picture:
https://lensandhues.wordpress.com/2016/01/05/quest/

Comment: Does the same thing happen when you use autofocus? Can you post an example image? What processing do you do to the RAW file? Your question needs more detail...

Comment: Clarity issue happens with both AF and MF when i zoom in the picture.

Comment: Have you read [Why are my photos not crisp?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/50006/why-are-my-photos-not-crisp) and [Why do my images look different on my camera than when imported to my laptop?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/69657/why-do-my-images-look-different-on-my-camera-than-when-imported-to-my-laptop)

Comment: Which parts of the sample image are you worried about? The background has a rather pleasing blur, probably caused by a wide aperture (shallow depth of field). The ground just in front of the bird appears to be in the sharpest focus, so perhaps your focus is on the wrong spot? You could try the sharpening tools in Photoshop or Lightroom, too... they'll make the feathers sharper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do use manual focus. The blurring you experience can come from several facts:

1. Depending on the light conditions, you may not be very precise in focusing: your image may just be a little bit out of focus. This is typically the case in your sample image where the focus is in front of the head.
2. As your sample is a macro photo, remember that in macro the depth of field (the distance which is on focus) is very small, so even if the focus is perfect on the beak of your chicken the eye will already be out of focus and thus blurred. You can limit this problem by closing the lens, however this will require more light (or a higher iso setting).
3. If you do use manual focus because you have uncoupled lenses (typically old lenses with no electronic communication) you also have to manage the aperture manually and, as the viewfinder becomes dark when the lens is stepped down, it is convenient to shoot at the maximum aperture. As most lenses are less sharp wide open, this may be an additional source of softness in your images.