# Are any common (optical) filters useful to attenuate overwhelming blue spotlights in live music situations?

Tags: filters, sensor, concert, stage-lighting

Strong blue spotlights as typically used on outdoor stages are often so physically bright (which I guess they have to be, given how viewers perceive blue as very dark) that they provoke channel saturation, banding, solarization and similar effects especially at higher ISOs.

Are any common (not $200 medical/scientific optics style unless they would be REALLY effective :) ) filters, like certain grades of yellow/orange, heavy UV filters, etc., effective at cutting the blue light back enough that the saturation effects are curbed, even if that means color balance will need to be restored heavily in postprocessing?

Comment: For why you would not want to use a color filter if you intend to reverse the effect of the filter in post-processing, please see the comment stream to [this answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/80576/15871) to [Do I still need to use color filters for images that are to be presented in monochrome (B&W)?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/80575/15871).

Comment: Do you have a sample image?  You mention yellow/orange filters.  Have you tried any?  White balance should be able to handle yellow/orange because it's on the normal color temperature scale.

Comment: Related: [Blown out blue/red light making photos look out of focus](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/73453/15871) and [Do colored LED lights produce less illuminance than traditional spotlights?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/82822/15871) and

Comment: For why putting a flat filter in front of your lens is not usually a wise option when shooting in theatrical lighting settings (such as most live music events), please see: [What kind of filter (if any) should I use when photographing a theater scene?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/63731/15871) or any of the questions here with the [ghosting](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ghosting) tag

Comment: Also related: [concert lighting difficulty with blue lighting - how to fix?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/108366/15871)